# Windows Azure Virtual Machine with GoDaddy Custom Domains

Tags: dns, cname, azure-virtual-machine

I am having problems setting up a custom domain (purchased on GoDaddy.com) with an Azure virtual machine (on which I plan on running multiple websites.) I've setup some `Endpoints` (80 for Http and 443 for SSL) I am using the `CNAME` of `myvm.cloudapp.net` and I set the binding in the VM IIS to my Azure VM `INTERNAL IP ADDRESS`. Voila, it all works. The problem is that Azure will change this IP every once in a while...so my question is, is there a better way to set this up so that I don't have to worry about IP address changes?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search keyword you are looking for is "dynamic DNS".

Set up a dynamic DNS account somewhere (e.g. http://www.noip.com/free/, or DynDns, there are many others). You will get a host name from them, and some client software that you run that keeps their DNS servers updated (some routers have dynamic-dns clients built in to their hardware as well). Then add a CNAME entry for your real domain/subdomain that points to your dynamic dns host name. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS for a general overview.

Your DNS provider may also have their own dynamic DNS client software that just works with their service - ask them if they support dynamic DNS (or search on their support site). Personally, I skip the middle men and just use ZoneEdit's nameservers (http://www.zoneedit.com/dynamicDNS.html, not free) for all DNS services. They have dynamic DNS support.